# Is it bad practice to work with datatypes that consist of less bits than the cpu's register size? Expressiveness of the code put aside

Tags: c#, windows

So im working with serialization alot where i compress loads of longs and ints down to their percentage of maxvalue and store them as a byte to the HD.

Now I was wondering if I could have less of an RAM impact if I used more bytes and shorts in my running code. To my knowledge this would have a negative impact on my OP/s as the CPU converts all values smaller than its register size up to match it.

Is the same true for the ram? I.E slot sizes are fixed size and a byte would take up just as much space as an int? Or is there something like labeled slots that signify the datatype, so that you could fill a slot with 2 bytes, one on the first 8 bits and another on the following 8, this storing 2 values in one slot?

Comment: you just have to benchmark it. i mean this question is related to C# thus how c# translate type. prety much complicated.

Comment: This is getting into really low level stuff. I gotta say, IMHO, the changes in performance would be so small you'd never see the difference. But I'm not expert in low level stuff though, so take my comment with a cube of salt